# Getting error when i click update using a gridview in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Im learning to use a `gridview` and a problem that im seeing is that putting an edit command in the `gridview` so that I can update a particular row. When I click the edit, it turns to the update as expected, I hit the update and the particular field turns the row into editable textboxes which is expected. The problem that I notice is that if I click another row, I get this error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

My question is why is this error occuring? Here is my code gridview below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Product" HeaderText="Product" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" />

        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
    </Columns>
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#99CCFF" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Have you tried what the error message recommends?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation.aspx

Comment: Create empty project, add there Grid and try to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell what the specific issue is from the description you've provided, but you can probably work around the issue by disabling event validation.

Add the following to the page directive:

```
EnableEventValidation="false"
```

You should note that you lose some security benefits by doing this, but it should fix the error.